# What is method by reflection in Java reflection API?

Tags: java, reflection

What is the method that we can use instead of the Java reflection API?  How can we define it?  A source code example will be helpful.

Comment: What reflection api are you talking about?  What language are you using?  Please provide some context.

Comment: i am using java.I am talking about reflection api in java.

Comment: so you want an alternative to java reflection api for reflecting java code?

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to use reflection to accomplish.

Comment: Your question is rather vague. I suppose you could embed a scripting language e.g. Rhino (Javascript), and let the scripting language use reflection behind the scenes.

Comment: Seemed like a reasonable question to me, given that we went through this exact thing a few weeks ago.

Comment: @anurag If you would like to see this question reopened, my suggestion to you is that you get more specific as to what you are trying to do with reflection (such as access a method dynamically), and perhaps provide an example. In the absence of further details, however, and if you were asking the general "what would I use this for" question, then this question may be better posed on the Programmers site where open-ended questions are encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

JDK 1.6 has the ability to dynamically compile Java classes (see [getSystemJavaCompiler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html)). If you don't want to use reflection (we're using dynamic compilation for performance reasons) then this is a reasonable approach.

Create a Java source file from a string containing the code:

```
   public class JavaSourceFromString extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
       final String code;

       JavaSourceFromString(String name, String code) {
           super(URI.create("string:///" + name.replace('.','/') + Kind.SOURCE.extension),
                 Kind.SOURCE);
           this.code = code;
       }

       @Override
       public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) {
           return code;
       }
   }

static final String sourceCode = ""
        + "import org.example.MySomethingObject;"
        + "public class GetSomethingDynamically implements DynamicStringGetter {\n" // DynamicStringGetter would define getString as a standard way to get a String from an object
        + "    public String getString(Object o) {\n"
        + "        MySomethingObject obj = (MySomethingObject) o;\n"
        + "        return o.getSomething();\n"
        + "    }\n"
        + "}\n";

   JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
   StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);

   List<JavaFileObject> jFiles = new ArrayList<JavaFileObject>();
   jFiles.add(new JavaSourceFromString("org.example.DynamicClass", sourceCode));

   compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, jFiles).call();
```

Then you load the newly created class files dynamically.

Alternatively, use byte code manipulation (such as [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/)) to create classes on the fly.

Both of these methods are a good deal more complex than standard reflection, but can have significant performance improvements over reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you use the Reflection API, that's because you need to dynamically access the content of a class, and there is no other way to do it. Please add more details (what exactly are you trying to achieve?) if you want a more detailled answer :)